# What is the use of Check gas limit in Chainlink Keepers?

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-keepers

In chainlink keepers document [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/). There is a conf called `checkGasLimit` with 6,500,000 as the default value.

Since the computation in `checkUpKeep` is expected to be outsourced off-chain, why there is a configuration called `checkGasLimit` where computation is off-chain?

Or `checkGasLimit` is for the situation where function `checkUpKeep` is supposed to modify some state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it!

`checkUpkeep` can be used to change the state of the blockchain. The Chainlink nodes will call the `checkUpkeep` function when it returns true - and if it costs gas, it will use gas.

The use of the `checkGasLimit` then, is to make sure they don't use too much gas. Per the docs:

`The maximum amount of gas that can be used by your checkUpkeep for off-chain computation.`

Comment: If checkUpkeep is for off-chain compute, how does it change the state of the blockchain?  Or does off chain compute also have the ability to make on-chain changes to state?

Comment: Hi @ZeusLawyer, I believe you can use checkUpKeep to change the state of the blockchain. Chainlink node does not care if the checkUpKeep changes the state or not, the node just call performUpKeep if the checkUpkeep returns true.

Comment: additional information on how the offchain simulation works and the role of the check gas limit configuration parameter can be found in @RoundAboutPi's detailed answer to another question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133319/are-chainlink-keepers-a-security-liability)